# Does interfaces effect performance because of reducing dependencies in Java Compiler or Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, architecture, interface

Assume two different scenarios:

- a) Each (service) class X has an interface `X` and exactly one implemntation `XImpl`. Every other (service) class (for example `YImpl`) always interacts with other (service) classes through there interface (`X`), but never directly refer to the implementation class (`XImpl`) -- This is at least a very common pattern.
- b) Just like a) but without all the interfaces. There is only `XImpl` and `YImpl` it refers directly to `YImpl`.

(*I guess I know a lot of the purposes of `a)` and `b)`, so please do not discuss that here.*)

My Question is: Does variant b) has a negative performance effect when working with Eclipse, Maven and M2E 1.0?

I can imagine this, because I you have way `a)` and you editing something in `XImpl` it does not effect `YImpl` because they are completely decoupled by interface `X`. But when removing the interfaces in `b)` so they are not longer decoupled.

Comment: There might be a bit of extra overhead from `invokeInterface` vs `invokeSpecial` calls (as JB Nizet posted, it's in the order of a few microseconds), but the 1-on-1 scenario is something I believe HotSpot can optimize for (if I had references to cite, I'd post this as an answer instead of a comment). The use or disuse of interfaces should be dictated by architecture and maintainability concerns. They're easily overused, but they have their place.

Comment: @Barend Garvelink: the runtime performance indications are clear, that is not the point of the question. And yes it is about the architecture, beause at least there is no other requirement left for the interfaces, so my last fear is that the editor will cause trouble.

Comment: D'oh, I didn't read the question well enough sorry.

Comment: @meriton: it is more a general question about architecture. But in the concrete cast it round about 50 to 100 of this services. But the complete code base is about 500 to 1000 classes in the complete eclipse project, plus 150 to 200 external jars.  This 50 to 100 services work a bit like the central classes, so they refer a lot of other classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to sacrifice the design of your application to gain 2 micro-seconds each time Eclipse or Maven compiles your classes. BTW, if you edit XImpl, it has to check that it still respects the contract of the X interface which is used by YImpl, so it probably doesn't make any difference.

Comment: "if you edit XImpl, it has to check that it still respects the contract of the X interface which is used by YImpl". Yes but then it can stop. If there is no interface, I don't know where Eclipse stops the validation process, or at least if it makes a notable difference.